# Button Android Developer Tools Build: issue with v22.6.2

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a problem in the latest version of Android Developer Tools Build: v22.6.2-1085508

It's very different where the previous version only had a layout and also extends the ActionBarActivity appears you previously only used Activity

Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // add the listener.
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);

        // you can define too a listener to your button1.
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.textView1:
            tv.setText("hola");
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            tv.setText("click on button1");
            break;
        default:
            // code..
            break;
        }
    }

}

public class sdfsdsdf {

}
```

Log Cat:

```
04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                   04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{com.example.htapex_ame/com.example.htapex_ame.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.example.htapex_ame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                    04-03 07:13:20.305: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  ... 11 more
                    04-03 07:13:20.315: W/ActivityManager(286):   Force finishing activity com.example.htapex_ame/.MainActivity
                    04-03 07:13:20.325: W/WindowManager(286): Failure taking screenshot for (123x164) to layer 21010
                    04-03 07:13:20.525: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:20.535: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
                    04-03 07:13:20.715: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:20.745: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:20.845: W/ActivityManager(286): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40e18340 u0 com.example.htapex_ame/.MainActivity}
                    04-03 07:13:20.885: D/dalvikvm(405): JIT unchain all for threadid=1
                    04-03 07:13:20.925: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:20.965: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.195: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1402K, 29% free 4964K/6912K, paused 933ms, total 949ms
                    04-03 07:13:21.555: I/Choreographer(405): Skipped 362 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.675: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.775: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.835: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.935: I/Choreographer(286): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
                    04-03 07:13:21.975: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 665K, 30% free 4877K/6912K, paused 333ms, total 335ms
                    04-03 07:13:22.185: I/Process(971): Sending signal. PID: 971 SIG: 9
```

xml file fragment_main:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.htapex_ame.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml file activity_main:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.button_a.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
</FrameLayout>`
```

Comment: What's at line 33 of your main activity?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing wrong with the new update of developer tools.

If I am not wrong you have posted xml of the fragment and not activity.
If you would jhave a look at your activity xml you will find the frameLayout corresponding to its fragment.

And for that you need to study fragments and all.

Besides you need to put your code in the onCreateView of the fragment class.

```
   tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text View1);
    // add the listener.
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);

    // you can define too a listener to your button1.
    btn1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And make TextView and Button as static.